# Class constructor Controller canno tbe invoked without 'new' error Stimulus + webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, stimulusjs

I have a project where Im trying to install stimulus and [stimulus tailwind components](https://github.com/excid3/tailwindcss-stimulus-components)

I added webpack and a webpack config file :

```
// Webpack uses this to work with directories
const path = require('path');

// This is the main configuration object.
// Here, you write different options and tell Webpack what to do
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  // Path to your entry point. From this file Webpack will begin its work
  entry: './src/js/index.js',

  // Path and filename of your result bundle.
  // Webpack will bundle all JavaScript into this file
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  // Default mode for Webpack is production.
  // Depending on mode Webpack will apply different things
  // on the final bundle. For now, we don't need production's JavaScript
  // minifying and other things, so let's set mode to development
  mode: 'development'
};
```

From what I understand using babel should transpile my es6 js to browser compatible js.

Then in src/index.js I have the stimulus code :

// Start StimulusJS

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const application = Application.start();

// Import and register all TailwindCSS Components
import { Alert, Autosave, Dropdown, Modal, Tabs, Popover, Toggle, Slideover } from "tailwindcss-stimulus-components"
application.register('alert', Alert)
application.register('autosave', Autosave)
application.register('dropdown', Dropdown)
application.register('modal', Modal)
application.register('tabs', Tabs)
application.register('popover', Popover)
application.register('toggle', Toggle)
application.register('slideover', Slideover)
```

and in the html file I require my bundle.js :

```
<script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

However I keep getting this error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Class constructor Controller cannot
> be invoked without 'new'
> from
> tailwindcss-stimulus-components.module.js:12

Here's a link to the [project](https://github.com/DavidGeismarLtd/b2b_dashboard_front)

Is there something wrong with my webpack setup? How can I fix this error?

Comment: There's a github discussion about this issue, maybe it would help? Link: https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/issues/433